# How to construct spring.messaging.message object from MIME content

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I trying to find out a helper/builder method which can construct the spring.messaging.message object from the text/plain content I receive from microsoft graph API which returns MIME version of an email.

Microsoft API = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{username}/messages/{messageId}/$value"

Once I get the response (which is in MIME version) I want to call my method

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "emailMessageChannel")
  public void processMessage(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
    MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
    String logMessage = this.getLogMessage(headers);
    try {
      this.initializeConcern(concernCode);
      LOGGER.warn("Email " + logMessage);
      emailProcessService.processEmailMessage(message, headers);
      LOGGER.warn("Processed email " + logMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      communicationChannelMetricUtil.conversationFailed(concernCode, communicationChannelId);
      LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while processing email " + logMessage, e);
    }
    finally {
      this.cleanUpConcern();
    }
  }

  public void processEmailMessage(Message<?> message, MessageHeaders headers) throws Exception {
    // extract details from header
    if (payload instanceof MimeMultipart) {
      this.processMimeMultipartEmail(conversation, (Message<MimeMultipart>) message, communicationChannel);
    }
    else if (payload instanceof String) {
      this.procesStringEmail(conversation, (Message<String>) message, communicationChannel);
    }
    else {
      // throw exception
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, not clear what is your problem. The signature of that service activator is OK. What else you'd like to hear from us, please?

Comment: I want to convert the graph API response (which is MIME version) to spring.messaging Message object and was trying to find out a helper class which converts the text version of MIME to message object. but now its not required.

thanks for replying to the question

Comment: In general you don't need to create Spring Message, just have a transformer and produce an expected object which would become a payload of the output message.